# python numpyのブロードキャストとは？

Tags: python

numpy配列の内積を取るときにエラーが出てしまいます
mat型のときはnp.dotが使えるというような文をどこかで見たので
np.matをしてみましたがndarrayから変わっておらず意味が分かりません
1行784列と784行392列の行列の積を計算したいです

```
print type(data)
data = list(data)
data[1] = list(data[1])
print type(data[1][0])
data[1][0][k] = np.mat(data[1][0][k])
print type(data[1][0][k])
print data[1][0][k].shape
print type(R)
print R.shape
data[1][0][k] = np.dot(data[1][0][k] , R)

<type 'tuple'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(784,)
<class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'>
(784, 392)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hoge.py", line 268, in <module>
data[1][0][k] = np.dot(data[1][0][k] , R)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (392) into shape (784)
```

また、

```
data[1][0][k] = np.dot(np.transpose(data[1][0][k]) , R)
```

をしてみたところ、

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,784) (784,392)
```

と出てしまいます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[1][0][k] = np.dot(data[1][0][k] , R)
```

の部分を

```
print(np.dot(data[1][0][k], R).shape)
```

とか

```
print(np.dot(data[1][0][k], R).shape)
```

してみてください。行列積計算は問題ないことが確認できると思います。

1行784列と784行392列の行列の積は1行392列の行列になりますね。それを`data[1][0][k] =  〜`として、784要素のndarrayにセットしようとして失敗してます。
代入先の変数名を間違えているとかそういったことじゃないでしょうか。